# How can I access an instance field in an abstract parent class via reflection?

Tags: java, reflection, abstract-class

So, for example, `StringBuilder` inherits from the abstract class `AbstractStringBuilder`. As I understand it, `StringBuilder` has no fields itself (except for `serialVersionUID`). Rather, its state is represented by the fields in `AbstractStringBuilder` and manipulated by calling `super` in the implementations of the methods it overrides.

Is there a way via reflection to get the private `char` array named `value` declared in `AbstractStringBuilder` that is associated with a particular instance of `StringBuilder`? This is the closest I got.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test
{
   public static void main(String[ ] args) throws Exception
   {
      StringBuilder foo = new StringBuilder("xyzzy");
      Field bar = foo.getClass( ).getSuperclass( ).getDeclaredField("value");
      bar.setAccessible(true);
      char[ ] baz = (char[ ])bar.get(new StringBuilder( ));
   }
}
```

That gets me an array of sixteen null characters. Note that I'm looking for solutions involving reflection, since I need a general technique that isn't limited to `StringBuilder`. Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you think that the Object class has a field called value?

Comment: @Roflcoptr I don't think that. `AbstractStringBuilder` has a field called `value`.

Comment: Hmm If i look in the API, StringBuilder inherits directly from object

Comment: @Roflcoptr Yeah, not sure why the documentation's off, but you can can test this for yourself by calling `getSuperclass` on `StringBuilder.class`. It actually inherits from `AbstractStringBuilder`.

Comment: `AbstractStringBuilder` is a package-private/default-access class. It's not part of the API, other than that it is mentioned in the serialisation docs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
char[ ] baz = (char[ ])bar.get(new StringBuilder( ));
```

Your problem is that you're inspecting a new StringBuilder... so of course it's empty (and 16 chars is the default size). You need to pass in `foo`

Comment: Well, I'll be damned. I'm not sure why it didn't occur to me to try that. Looks like it works. Thank you.

Comment: Can you explain why this works? How can you get the value of a private field in some class from an instance of a subclass of that class, which doesn't inherit it?

Comment: The private field is still part of the child object, it's just not accessible from within the child by the standard means. As an interesting aside, a private field is actually private to the *class* not the *instance* - I'd be keen to know the why behind that one.

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth looking in the Apache Commons BeanUtils library. Here is the link to their [API Javadocs](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/v1.8.3/apidocs/index.html). The library contains lots of high-level methods that make Reflection easier to use.