# How can I reference a field of a subclass from the abstract superclass?

Tags: c#, inheritance, reflection

Similar: [How can I access an instance field in an abstract parent class via reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4361714/1026459), but only in name, no one actually uses or references reflection there.

Constraints:

C#

Must use an abstract class to inherit from

Must be able to pass in string as field identifier (willing to negotiate)

```
public class ViewModel : BaseClass
{
 public Car Car { get; set; }
}
public abstract class BaseClass
{
 public object GetField(string field){
  //return Car if .GetField("Car") is called
 }
}
```

I assume this requires reflection but couldn't quite wrap my head around it. How can access the field Car as in this example?

Comment: If the abstract class should know of it's childrens properties, then it should probably be put within the the abstract class.

Comment: @Matthew - In most cases, yes. I agree. For the more complex superset of this subset example, I actually need to not have the abstract class know.

Comment: @Matthew I'm assuming this is being used as part of something like `INotifyPropertyChanged`, where you only get the name of the property that changed.  You could then put code in the base class to log the property and value.

Comment: @cadrell0 - This is part of generic serialization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
[TestFixture]
public class TravisSerialisationTest
{
    [Test]
    public void GetPropertyValueTest()
    {
        var volvo = "Volvo";
        var viewModel = new ViewModel() { Car = volvo };
        var field = viewModel.GetField(() => viewModel.Car);
        Assert.AreEqual(volvo,field);
    }
}

public class ViewModel : BaseClass
{
    public string Car { get; set; }
}

public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public T GetField<T>(Expression<Func<T>> propertyExpression )
    {
        return propertyExpression.Compile().Invoke();
    }
}
```

Comment: Because this requires casting the object to type `ViewModel`, why wouldn't you just use `viewModel.Car`?  I don't think this would work if you change the line `var viewModel = new ViewModel() { Car = volvo };` to `BaseClass viewModel = new ViewModel() { Car = volvo };`

Comment: Does it still work, if `viewModel` is of type `BaseClass` and not `ViewModel`? I understand the requirements in a way that it should work then too.

Comment: The GetField<T> method provides no benefit over invoking viewModel.Car directly, and has the added performance hit of having to compile an expression.

Comment: @JamesCurtis As it is written not the GetField<T> does the same thing as viewModel.Car. The benefit is if you want to do something In the GetField, say it was public void SerializeField<>( ... )
But that is the answer to ops question as it is phrased.

Comment: It will not work with BaseClass viewModel because viewModel will not have a .Car property then. If that is the case you would have to pass property name and all kinds of ugly. I can see use of ops method, was implementing about the exact same thing at work today (for serialization)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
    public class ViewModel : BaseClass
    {
        public string Car { get; set; }
    }
    public abstract class BaseClass
    {
        public object GetField(string name)
        {
            MemberInfo member = GetType()
                .GetMember( name, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static )
                .FirstOrDefault();
            if(member == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            PropertyInfo property = member as PropertyInfo;
            if(property != null)
            {
                return property.GetValue( this, null );
            }
            FieldInfo field = member as FieldInfo;
            if(field != null)
            {
                return field.GetValue( this );
            }
            return null;
         }
    }
```

Comment: Do you need to call `GetGetMethod` on the PropertyInfo.  Can't you just use `GetValue`?